# ElasticSearch Boolean Query Result Mismatch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, boolean-logic, nosql

This is my index mapping

```
   "index":{
      "mappings":{
         "patient":{
            "properties":{
               "LastName":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "accountType":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "civilStatus":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "consultations":{
                  "type":"nested",
                  "properties":{
                     "deleted":{
                        "type":"boolean"
                     },
                     "diagnosis":{
                        "type":"string",
                        "index":"not_analyzed"
                     },
                     "documentDate":{
                        "type":"date",
                        "format":"dateOptionalTime"
                     },
                     "firstName":{
                        "type":"string"
                     },
                     "lastName":{
                        "type":"string"
                     },
                     "middleName":{
                        "type":"string"
                     },
                     "prescriptions":{
                        "type":"string"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "firstName":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "gender":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "id":{
                  "type":"string",
                  "index":"not_analyzed"
               },
               "lastName":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "middleName":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "occupation":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "owner":{
                  "type":"string",
                  "index":"not_analyzed"
               },
               "patientPin":{
                  "type":"string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the only saved data on ElasticSearch

```
{
   "_index":"index",
   "_type":"patient",
   "_id":"TENANT1100066",
   "_score":1.0,
   "_source":{
      "id":"100066",
      "firstName":"Johnny",
      "patientPin":"201408000001",
      "middleName":"John ",
      "consultations":[
         {
            "id":null,
            "prescriptions":[

            ],
            "diagnosis":[
               "headache of unknown origin"
            ],
            "documentDate":"2014-08-05T10:10:00.000+08:00",
            "deleted":false,
            "lastName":"David",
            "firstName":"Johnny ",
            "middleName":"John "
         }
      ],
      "owner":"TENANT1",
      "gender":"MALE",
      "occupation":"Unspecified",
      "accountType":"INDIVIDUAL",
      "civilStatus":"SINGLE",
      "lastName":"David"
   }
}
```

And here's the sample query I built to check how boolean query works.

```
{
  "nested" : {
    "query" : {
      "bool" : {
        "must" : [ {
          "match" : {
            "consultations.diagnosis" : {
              "query" : "Kawasaki's Disease",
              "type" : "phrase"
            }
          }
        }, {
          "match" : {
            "consultations.diagnosis" : {
              "query" : "Alcohol Intoxication",
              "type" : "phrase"
            }
          }
        } ],
        "must_not" : {
          "match" : {
            "consultations.deleted" : {
              "query" : "true",
              "type" : "boolean"
            }
          }
        },
        "should" : {
          "match" : {
            "consultations.diagnosis" : {
              "query" : "headache of unknown origin",
              "type" : "phrase"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "path" : "consultations"
  }
```

Apparently, Kawasaki's Disease and Fibriasis does not exist but headache of unknown origin exists but no 
results are returned(Which is Johnny John David) what am I missing here? The operation I had in my mind was
(Kawasaki's Disease AND Fibriasis) OR headache of unknown origin.

What I had in mind was if there was no patients with Kawasakis Disease AND Fibriasis search for Patients with "headache of unknown origin". Which clearly we have, but my query is returning 0 results. what Am I missing here

Answer (score 1):

In your query, you require that matching documents have both (Kawasaki's Disease AND Fibriasis) as you added these 2 conditions in the **must** clause.

Your document only match your **should** clause, so it doesn't appear in the search results.

To achieve what you want :

```
(Kawasaki's Disease AND Fibriasis) OR headache of unknown origin
```

You can embed the two diseases in another bool query and add this query in the should section of the root query, like this :

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "consultations",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [{
                  "match_phrase": {
                    "consultations.diagnosis": "Kawasaki's Disease"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "match_phrase": {
                    "consultations.diagnosis": "Alcohol Intoxication"
                  }
                }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "match_phrase": {
                "consultations.diagnosis": "headache of unknown origin"
              }
            }
          ],
          "minimum_number_should_match": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which outputs the previously indexed patient :

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.3007646,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "patient",
            "_id": "TENANT1100066",
            "_score": 0.3007646,
            "_source": {
               "id": "100066",
               "firstName": "Johnny",
               "patientPin": "201408000001",
               "middleName": "John ",
               "consultations": [
                  {
                     "id": null,
                     "prescriptions": [],
                     "diagnosis": [
                        "headache of unknown origin"
                     ],
                     "documentDate": "2014-08-05T10:10:00.000+08:00",
                     "deleted": false,
                     "lastName": "David",
                     "firstName": "Johnny ",
                     "middleName": "John "
                  }
               ],
               "owner": "TENANT1",
               "gender": "MALE",
               "occupation": "Unspecified",
               "accountType": "INDIVIDUAL",
               "civilStatus": "SINGLE",
               "lastName": "David"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```